# how to optimize images when uploading in media manager for joomla 3?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0, joomla-module

when i upload 4MB images into media manager it takes the image full size with out optimize which makes my site to load long time, how to reduce image size automatically when uploading file images like in wordpress which optimize automatically.

Comment: Have you checked the Joomla Extensions Directory for an extension that may do this? Either that or you could optimize them yourself before uploading

Comment: Right now it's not built in, though there is a project for it. YOu can either write code to use JImage or you as $lodder said use an extension that implements that feature.